# selection changed event in combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, selectionchanged

i have a requirement to do something after value of combox change. i tried selectionchanged event but that is not working because if hold the previous value(before committing the change). Is there any specific event for this? I tried on google but couldn't find anything. Please suggest if i need to create dynamic event for this or how to do that.
Experts..Let me know how to fix this.

Comment: `because if hold the previous value` - Are you sure n this?

Comment: Don't use events, use data-binding instead. Specifically, bind SelectedItem to the property in your class and respond to the change in that class's setter. If the setter is called then the property is in the process of being set, so there's no ambiguity or confusion as to whether or not it's happening.